# Loading child routers from database durandal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

i trying to create child routes in durandal 2 from my database starterkit without success.

Although I succeeded in rendering it with static contents as shown below:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout'], function (router, ko) {
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({
        moduleId: 'sectionGroups',
        fromParent: true
    }).map([
        { route: ['', 'child1'], moduleId: 'pages/child1', title: 'child1', nav: true },
        { route: 'child2: moduleId: 'pages/child2', title: 'child2',  nav: true },
        { route: 'child3', moduleId: 'pages/child3', title: 'child3',  nav: true }
    ]).buildNavigationModel();

return {
    router: childRouter
};
});
```

However I've been unable to dynamically output the the menus from the database. Am i doing somethig wrong? Please see my code below

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout','services/oasisManager', 'services/logger'], function (router, ko, om, logger) {

var pageRoutes = getPageRoutes();

var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({
        moduleId: 'sectionGroups',
        fromParent: true
    })
    .map(pageRoutes)
    .buildNavigationModel();

function getPageRoutes() {
    var pageRoutes = [];
    om.getOasis(134).done(function() {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(om.activeOasis.PageRoutes, function(item) {
            var nav = true;
            if (item.Route == '') {
                nav = false;
            }
            pageRoutes.push({
                route: item.Route,
                moduleId: item.ModuleId,
                title: item.Title,
                nav: nav
            });
        });
    });
    return pageRoutes;
}

return {
    router: childRouter
};
});
```

Html looks pretty much the same. Please help

```
<div class="container-fluid knockout-samples">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 well">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">Basic Examples</li>

            <!--ko foreach: router.navigationModel-->
            <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
            </li>
            <!--/ko-->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening in your code is that `getPageRoutes` is returning a blank array.  it should be returning a promise for a list of routes.  you probably need something like this.

```
function getPageRoutes() {
    return om.getOasis(134).done(function(routes) {
        var pageRoutes = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(routes, function(item) {
            var nav = true;
            if (item.Route == '') {
                nav = false;
            }
            pageRoutes.push({
                route: item.Route,
                moduleId: item.ModuleId,
                title: item.Title,
                nav: nav
            });
        });
        return pageRoutes;
    });
}
```

I am making the assumtion that `om.getOasis(134)` will return a promise of for a list of routes.

Not sure if this will help but this is what I have in my durandal app to do something similar to what you want to achieve.  I use the [Q promises library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) to handle the async calls to the webapi.

```
define(['plugins/http', 'services/logger'], function (http, logger) {
    "use strict";
    var getRoutes = function () {
        return http.get("routes/availableRoutes").then(function (data) {
            logger.log("Routes Loaded", data, 'services/routes', false);
            return data;
        });
    };
    var routes = {
        getRoutes: getRoutes
    };
    return routes;
});
```

The calling code then becomes something like the following.

```
return routes().then(function (availableRoutes) {
    return router.makeRelative({
        moduleId: 'sectionGroups',
        fromParent: true
    }) 
    .map(availableRoutes) 
    .buildNavigationModel()
    .activate();
});
```